# Calculus variation question

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Assume that we have to minimize the integral $I[y]=\int_0^1 L(x,y,y'(x))dx$ for smooth diffeomorphic mappings $y:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=1$, where $L\in C^\infty(R\times R\times R)$, and $L$ satisfies convex condition wrt to $y'$ and coercivity condition. Is the minimiser of $I$ the only diffeomorphic solution $y:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ of Euler-Lagrange equation $\partial_t (\partial_{y'} L)=\partial_y L$? Some reference I need.